# How to close an image at the opening of another - linux c ++

Tags: c++, linux, display, multiple-instances, fclose

if everything is not perfect I apologize;)
I am doing a program in c ++ that when it receives a sensor information, shows a picture with feh full screen.
The problem is that when I want to go from one image to another, It opens a new feh, until the moment when the computer crashes because it takes all the memory ...

How to make the opening of an image close the previous one?

This is my current command line :

```
system("feh -F ressources/icon_communication.png&");
```

I must specify that I also trigger a sound, but that there is no problem because the program closes automatically at the end of the sound:

```
system("paplay /home/pi/demo_ecran_interactif/ressources/swip.wav&");
```

Tried this as a test and works ! Thanks @paul-sanders !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

pid_t display_image_file (const char *image_file)
{
    pid_t pid = fork ();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not fork, error: " << errno << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid != 0)    // parent
        return pid;

    // child
    execlp ("feh", "-F", image_file, NULL); // only returns on failure
    std::cout << "Couldn't exec feh for image file " << image_file << ", error: " << errno << "\n";
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = display_image_file ("nav.png");
    if (pid != -1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (2000));
        kill (pid, SIGKILL);
    }

    pid_t pid2 = display_image_file ("sms2.png");
}
```

Comment: Do the commands work when issued in a standard command terminal?

Comment: You do need to wait for asynchronously running subprocesses, otherwise the OS will immediately kill these after your main process exits.

Comment: yes, the programm is working, when i compile and launch, everything is great, except that it crashes when the memory is full, because feh is launched multiple times. I don't understand what is "asynchronously running subprocesses" here :) The fact is that i don't know how to close feh when i open a new image with feh.

Comment: Have you tried doing a manual `fork`/`exec` instead of using `system`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work, i think i don't use the function properly but can't figure out why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooooooooo, the goal here (in terms of your test program) seems to be:

- display `nav.png` in `feh`
- wait 2 seconds
- close (that instance of) `feh`
- display `sms2.png` in `feh`

And if you can get the test program doing that then you will be on your way (I'm not going to worry my pretty little head about your sound issue (because it's 30+ degrees here today), but once you have your test program running right then you will probably be able to figure out how to solve that one yourself).

So, two issues that I see in your code here:

- you're not making any effort to close the first instance of 'feh'
- `execlp()` doesn't do quite what you probably think it does (specifically, it never returns, unless it fails for some reason).

So what I think you need to do is something like this (code untested, might not even compile and you need to figure out the right header files to #include, but it should at least get you going):

```
pid_t display_image_file (const char *image_file)
{
    pid_t pid = fork ();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not fork, error: " << errno << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    if (pid != 0)    // parent
        return pid;

    // child
    execlp ("feh", "-F", image_file, NULL); // only returns on failure
    std::cout << "Couldn't exec feh for image file " << image_file << ", error: " << errno << "\n";
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = display_image_file ("nav.png");
    if (pid != -1)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds (2000));
        kill (pid, SIGKILL);
    }

    pid_t pid = display_image_file ("sms2.png");
    // ...
}
```

Does that help?